# How to return value from recursive function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm working with binary tree in python. I need to create a method which searches the tree and return the best node where a new value can be inserted. But i'm have trouble returning a value from this recursive function. I'm a total newbie in python.

```
def return_key(self, val, node):
    if(val < node.v):
        if(node.l != None):
            self.return_key(val, node.l)
        else:
            print node.v
            return node
    else:
        if(node.r != None):
            #print node.v
            self.return_key(val, node.r)
        else:
            print node.v
            return node
```

Printing `node.v` prints the node value, but when i print the returned node :

```
print ((tree.return_key(6, tree.getRoot().v)))
```

it prints

> None

as result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to return the result of your *recursive* call. You are ignoring it here:

```
if(node.l != None):
    self.return_key(val, node.l)
```

and

```
if(node.r != None):
    self.return_key(val, node.r)
```

Recursive calls are no different from other function calls, you still need to handle the return value if there is one. Use a `return` statement:

```
if(node.l != None):
    return self.return_key(val, node.l)

# ...

if(node.r != None):
    return self.return_key(val, node.r)
```

Note that since `None` is a singleton value, you can and should use `is not None` here to test for the absence:

```
if node.l is not None:
    return self.return_key(val, node.l)

# ...

if node.r is not None:
    return self.return_key(val, node.r)
```

I suspect you are passing in the wrong arguments to the call to begin with however; if the second argument is to be a node, don't pass in the node value:

```
print(tree.return_key(6, tree.getRoot())) # drop the .v
```

Also, if all your `node` classes have the same method, you could recurse to that rather than using `self.return_value()`; on the `Tree` just do:

```
print tree.return_key(6)
```

where `Tree.return_key()` delegates to the root node:

```
def return_key(self, val):
    root = tree.getRoot()
    if root is not None:
        return tree.getRoot().return_key(val)
```

and `Node.return_key()` becomes:

```
def return_key(self, val):
    if val < self.v:
        if self.l is not None:
            return self.l.return_key(val)
    elif val > self.v:
        if self.r is not None:
            return self.r.return_key(val)

    # val == self.v or child node is None
    return self
```

I updated the `val` testing logic here too; if `val < self.v` (or `val < node.v` in your code) is false, *don't* assume that `val > self.v` is true; `val` could be equal instead.

Comment: I don't think adding a return statement there will do any good. Since every time the recursion ends it'll reach the else statement which already has a return function. That being said i did try adding the return statement. It still returns None

Comment: @Utsav: You have other errors too, I've updated my answer to address those.

Comment: I actually have two separate classes for Node and Tree. Here's  my code for the tree implemention

http://pastebin.com/wD17VdY6

Comment: @Utsav: right, so you have the option to implement separate `Tree.return_key()` and `Node.return_key()` methods. The same applies to `Tree.add()` and `Tree.printTree()`; these also recurse but could delegate the per-node recursion to `Node.*` methods instead.

Comment: Didn't quite get you, could be a little more clear please

Comment: @Utsav: Your `Tree._printTree` method could be implemented as a `Node.printNode()` method instead, so all `Tree.printTree()` has to do is call `self.root.printNode()`.